# Clear content of a locked logfile in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, locked-files

There are many explanations out there how to empty a log file.

Like:

```
File.WriteAllText(activeTab.FileName, string.Empty);
```

But this example and other examples I found all have the same problem. It do not work if the logfile is currently locked by another process.

In ruby there is a task I can use `rake log:clear` which do not remove, just empty the log files.

I found also that I can this with Powershell using `clc <filename>`.
The sources are available here now:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c1faf1e6e10fc1ce45e84ef6f49ae7136c67a111/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/ClearContentCommand.cs

But honestly I do not understand how this code works, also it inherits from other classes.

Is there a C# implementation available that I can use in any common program/class?

Comment: In short if a file is locked you (*you=any other process/thread*) can't delete it or modify ("empty") it. There are plenty of 3rd party logging libraries which I would recommend any day over trying to roll your own. Using a library will then ensure you do not have to worry about things like this as some of these libraries have been around for as long as I can remember and are very robust and configurable. My personal favorite is [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) but [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) is also very popular.

Comment: IMO, this is not a reasonable/safe thing to do.  You should figure out how to get whomever is holding the file lock to release it.

Comment: You CANNOT break another process's file lock. All you can do is queue the data somewhere and keep checking for the lock to be released and THEN fulfill your action (edit/delete/clear).

Comment: I can not release the lock as the service writing the logfile continue to run. The powershell cmdlet Clear-Content does exactly what this case is for.

Comment: Maybe I should specify that the file is "opened" by the process, I can still open it with e.g. notepad++ and clear it by hand. I am not sure if this is a different *lock*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the file can be cleared in my case using this snippet:

```
  var stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete);
  stream.Close();
```

Comment: Seems related to the fact that most managed-code tools (including PowerShell) omit the `FileShare.Delete` option when opening files.   Older, native-code apps generally open files with share/delete it allowed.   This is one of those cases where I like the old way better.